# RVM move path Selenium - Chromedriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rvm, watir

```
pry(main)> browser =Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
```

Error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:  Unable to find chromedriver. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.
from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.12.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:57:in `binary_path'
```

---

I have already installed and added the path for chrome driver however, I keep receiving this error, can someone highlight what i am missing.

Comment: Look at the answer where I have updated the binary path now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the chrome driver and put it in your bin folder, please go the path specified and download the chrome driver and then paste that to your bin folder. C:\Ruby\bin is what my path, likewise check your path and place `chromedriver.exe` file into bin folder

Setting binary path

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path = 'C:\Ruby24-x64\bin C:\Users\farid\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\application\chrome.exe'
```

Comment: this is my path, 
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\bin
as well the path for chrome 
C:\Users\farid\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\application

Comment: @Farida  Yes then paste your chrome driver there, it would work.

Comment: chromedriver already in the path, i can access to it direct and open properly on its port, however, I can;t let watir opens it

Comment: Okay actually you need give the binary path since your chrome is not in the program files, give me an hour once I reach office I will you that code.

Comment: you are the best

Comment: here is my path list:
C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\bin
C:\Ruby24-x64\bin
C:\Users\farid\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\application

_______
so ruby is installed using RailsInstaller and the Chromedriver is in the chrome application

Comment: @Farida I have updated the binary path for you, Can you check it now?

Comment: @Rajagppalan : it didn't work, i got the same error

Comment: @Farida take the binary path you specified and then paste it in the address bar and press enter and see whether chrome opens.

Comment: I did paste : 
C:\users\farid\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\application\chrome.exe
the browser : your file was not found. 

however, if I click on the file manually, it will launch the console
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 9515

Comment: @Farida I am not asking you to click , I am asking you copy this path and paste it in address bar and then press enter button and see whether chrome opens!

Comment: Rajagoplan: I reinstalled everything and now it works, thank you
i had to reinstall, Ruby, rails, rvm and chromedriver and all the gems . 
Thank you

Comment: @Farida Okay, you are welcome.